# jQuery script conflict / not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am trying to get `tinyscrollbar.js` working in my website, unfortunately it does not seem to work and I can't get my head around the issue.

http://www.luminous-living.com/issue/ <- have a look at my demo (click Information > About)

Does anybody know what the conflict is?

Some help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: For future reference, please post the relevent code in the question - that way this will be a useful reference for anyone who visits the page in the future.

Comment: Have you try jQuery.noConflict() functionality

Comment: Thank you Rory for the information

Comment: I have tried to add the jQuery.noConflict() functionality, unfortunately it does not seem to solve the problem as my sliding panels are not working once in use

Comment: You are correct, it's a hoop to jump through to make it work. You might want to try other libraries, or make sure you update them, because there might be conflicts that have been resolved. It's probably within the js somewhere, but there is a lot to sift through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: removed incorrect info

find these lines and remove "display:none;" from style:

```
<div id="information_list" style="display:none; float:left; width:380px; height:2500px; overflow:hidden; background:URL(assets/img/etlap_background.jpg) #2F3229; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:right bottom; ">

<div id="etel1" style="display:none; width:350px; margin-left:35px;">
```

After you remove the display:none; lines, you can see the scrollbar works. Maybe that will narrow it down.

After further testing, the problem has to do with "display:none;". I used visibility="hidden" for information_list, removed the display:none; on the sub element with the scroll, and toggled that and it worked.

Maybe take display:none; out of the html and try in css (in case that will have different functionality) or trigger by javascript after pageload from visibility back to display.

.. ok, just tried with css. That doesn't work. I think if you want to use display:none on that element (and it's parents) you need to trigger it with js.

Comment: Thank you craniumonempty - that does to seem make the scrollbar working.

Comment: thank your for the detailed clarification. that seems to be very tricky to get this resolved

Answer (score 0):

you have some error in your javascript, you must correct them otherwise javascript execution stops and it's difficult to understand what works and what doesn't. The errors are:

```
document.getElementById(link+'_'+i).className="almenu"; (line 114)
```

**document.getElementById(link + "_" + i) is null**

and

```
document.images.menu5.src='assets/img/nav_contact.png'; (line 129)
```

**document.images.menu5 is undefined**

Comment: Ciao Nicola - thank you for the information - I have edited the functionality although I am still making no progress in resolving the scrollbar issue. Do you might have an idea?

Comment: @David you should post your code so that it's easier to help. Try to post only the code that is relevant to the question. post your markup too.

Comment: I am currently using the following code below for the tinyscrollbar

        <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar();
        });
        </script> 

As you can see in my demo http://www.luminous-living.com/issue/ (information > about) it gets integrated although something seems to block the scroll functionality - it does not work.